# s3fs-fuse encrypt/securely store passwords

Tags: s3fs

We are following this instruction to mount S3 bucket to a machine  using this below instruction:

> https://docs.jdcloud.com/en/object-storage-service/s3fs

Question mark :
we are storing plain text  secrets/keys in a file required to mount, is there any other way we can avoid exposing plain text something can we encrypt or store somewhere. For example, we are mounting with  "-o password.." with this, we will find this in the process daemon like lsof. Hence. We need security fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

The keys need to exist somewhere for s3fs to use them.  You can provide them via `${HOME}/.aws/credentials`, `-o passwd_file`, or the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` environment variables.  The latter might be better if you don't want to persist the credentials to local storage but you should be careful that you don't accidentally include this in your shell history or similar.